# Custom Object Count

Tags: posts

We have a job board where the client wants to increase the registered job seeker count. I understand that this count is a default function in WP. Is there a way to adjust or modify it?

Thanks
Dan

Comment: Are you looking to modify the numbers next to categories? I.E. "Category Name (3)" denotes there are X posts in Y category. Could you narrow down which function is outputting these numbers?

Comment: Perhaps some count of users with a specific role? As Howdy implies, job boards and job seekers are not a part of WordPress core - without elaboration on what they are and where such a count is displayed it is not possible to answer this question.